# Loop in python - Repeat sentence, changing only the number inside

Tags: python, loops

I have a sequence :

```
    ['Valor','005 - 001']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 001');
    ['Valor','007 - 001']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 001');
    ['Valor','019 - 001']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 001');
    ['Valor','024 - 001']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 001');


    ['Valor','005 - 002']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 002');
    ['Valor','007 - 002']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 002');
    ['Valor','019 - 002']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 002');
    ['Valor','024 - 002']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 002');


    ['Valor','005 - 003']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 003');
    ['Valor','007 - 003']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 003');
    ['Valor','019 - 003']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 003');
    ['Valor','024 - 003']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 003');

....
```

Where the only thing that changes on each line is the number after the hyphen :

```
['Valor','005 - 001']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - 001');
```

How can I loop this value from "001" through "030"?

I have tried:

```
for x in range(001,030):
print ( "['Valor','005 -" x"']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - "x"');
    ['Valor','007 - "x"']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - "x"');
    ['Valor','019 - "x"']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - "x"');
    ['Valor','024 - "x"']=>DB('Cubo_Amostra_Cons',!Ano,'000 - "x"');")
```

But I didn't get the right sequence.

Comment: I'm not clear how your original data are stored! Is that a big string? In the loop you are just printing a string, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: "didn't get the right sequence" doesn't quite make it.  What *did* you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to format the value string:

```
for x in range(20, 30):
    x_str = str(x).zfill(3)
```

... and use that in your output.  Also, you can parameterize your four variations:

```
class = [5, 7, 19, 24]
for post in range(20, 30):
    post_str = str(post).zfill(3)
    for pre in class:
        pre_str = str(pre).zfill(3)
        valor_str = pre_str + " - " + post_str
        cons_str  = "000 - " + post_str
        # Here, valor_str in the first label you want;
        #        cons_str is the last.
```

Can you finish from there?

Note that the final value listed in `range` isn't used; I believe you want

```
for post in range(1, 31):
```

Answer (score 0):

python is an array-based language and can be vectorized.
Please use vectors (arrays) instead of for loop in order to have a better performance.